# How To get Mobile Number in android studio?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

How To get Mobile Number in android studio? I try to get my mobile number using this code but return value is blank.

```
TelephonyManager tpm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tpm.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: Did you add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> permission?

Comment: I  also add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> permission.

Comment: What is the Android version that you are trying?

Comment: I try on Marshmallows device.

Comment: Please check the answer which I have added.

Comment: Also the phone number info is **optional**. Phones do not need it to be able to make and receive calls. So many phone companies just leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the relevant documantation for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

> getLine1Number
>
> String getLine1Number () Returns the phone number string for line 1,
>   for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is
>   unavailable.
>
> The default SMS app can also use this.
>
> Requires the READ_PHONE_STATE, READ_SMS or READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
>   permissions.

Also if you are using Android 6.0 or above add the following code.
This code checks whether the app has permission to read the user's contacts or not also it requests the permission from the user if necessary. Try this

```
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

}
}
```